# How to see kafka producer metrics using spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api, spring-boot-actuator

I want to see Kafka producer `JMX` metrics using Spring boot actuator. How can I see those metrics using spring boot? AN example will be much appriciated

Answer (score -1):

You can use [Spring Boot Admin](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow-server-cloudfoundry/docs/1.2.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/configuration-monitoring-management.html).
You'll create a Spring Boot Admin application and have your producer register itself with it. Here's a nice [tutorial](https://medium.com/singhal-labs/microservices-spring-boot-admin-what-it-is-how-it-helps-you-in-managing-and-monitoring-5a1523ff0e6b).